# TYPO3 9.x and slug history

Tags: slug, typo3-9.x, realurl

In pre v9.5 websites I used realurl.

When you change the site-title from `tileV1` to `tilteV2` the page could be accessed with `domain.tld/titlev1.html` AND `domain.tld/titlev2.html`.

The realurl path of `titlev1` was marked as MovedPermanent (and redirects)  to titlev2 and an expire date for the v1 is sent to the browser (+30 days).

My editors don't care a lot about SEO and the rest. They copy pages, deleting the content, moving them around the pagetree - nobody cares about the slug, often this is `default-titlexx.html`.

With realurl this was less painful compared to the native URL-handling in TYPO3.

I could not find any documents/websites discussing the problem.

Am I missing some option to set? How do you solve this?

Training the editors to double check the slug, but this only works for 2 days then I get the next error report: The page is broken cause a page has moved...

Thanks for any help in this issue!

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between TYPO3 9 and 10. In 10 you have additionally functionality which handles this:

- when changing a slug, TYPO3 offers to change the slugs of the subpages - the editor gets a choice to do this or not
- redirects will get created automatically, here you also have the choice to allow redirects for subpages as well.

You might also want to look at the extensions that are available for TYPO3 9 which try to enhance the Slug handling, e.g. [sluggi](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sluggi). (I have not used this myself, but it looks like it may be helful).

There are also a number of open [issues](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&set_filter=1&f%5B%5D=status_id&op%5Bstatus_id%5D=o&f%5B%5D=category_id&op%5Bcategory_id%5D=%3D&v%5Bcategory_id%5D%5B%5D=1598&f%5B%5D=&c%5B%5D=tracker&c%5B%5D=status&c%5B%5D=priority&c%5B%5D=subject&c%5B%5D=assigned_to&c%5B%5D=category&c%5B%5D=fixed_version&c%5B%5D=cf_7&group_by=&t%5B%5D=) about Slug handling and redirects.

---

What I would recommend

1. Think about updating to 10. There are not quite so many breaking changes and you might find the update quite painless. Or look at the [slug extensions](https://extensions.typo3.org/?tx_solr%5Bfilter%5D%5B0%5D=typo3%3A9%20LTS&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=slug).
2. Familiarize yourself with the slug and redirect handling (in v10). (Yes, the documentation may be incomplete but a lot of it is self-explanatory. Just test changing Slugs on some pages with subpages and move a page and the functionality should reveal itself).
3. Using permissions (possibly also workspaces) you can restrict what editors may do. You might also want to restrict editing to some pages (e.g. editlock, permissions). If they can't handle something responsibly, maybe they should only have restricted access. (I realize this is not so easy to solve, we have the same problem and defining very fine-grained permissions makes it impossible to handle at some point. Also, the editors should be able to create new pages).

Sorry, I don't have all the answers right now. To be honest, our site is a little messed up in this respect currently, because of using TYPO3 9 for a while and not handling this problem. At some point, the URLs of subpages start to deviate and then it is difficulty to get it cleaned up.

What is better now, though: In realurl the editors often did not fill out the URL segment and then the URL changed every time the page title changed. This is now handled in a better way, I think, where you explicitly have to define the URL.